# How can I speed up a Group By statement with multiple Joins?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

I am having trouble trying to speed up a query that's taking about 11 seconds on only 2 million rows. [Here is a link to my sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0d32c3). And here is the statement I am trying to run and my EXPLAIN statement.

The Query:

```
SELECT crawl.pk Pk,domains.domain Domain, 
CONCAT(schemes.scheme, "://", domains.domain, remainders.remainder) Uri, 
crawl.redirect Redirect FROM crawl 
LEFT JOIN dates ON crawl.date_crawled=dates.pk     
LEFT JOIN schemes ON crawl.scheme=schemes.pk 
LEFT JOIN domains ON crawl.domain=domains.pk 
LEFT JOIN remainders ON crawl.remainder=remainders.pk 
WHERE (dates.date < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY) 
AND crawl.redirect=0 
GROUP BY crawl.domain 
ORDER BY crawl.date_crawled ASC 
LIMIT 50
```

EXPLAIN:

```
+----+-------------+------------+--------+-----------------------+-----------------------+---------+----------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type   | possible_keys         | key                   | key_len | ref                        | rows   | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+-----------------------+-----------------------+---------+----------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | dates      | ALL    | PRIMARY,date          | NULL                  | NULL    | NULL                       |      7 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | crawl      | ref    | date_crawled_redirect | date_crawled_redirect | 8       | mytable.dates.pk,const     | 408644 |                                              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | schemes    | eq_ref | PRIMARY               | PRIMARY               | 4       | mytable.crawl.scheme       |      1 |                                              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | domains    | eq_ref | PRIMARY               | PRIMARY               | 4       | mytable.crawl.domain       |      1 |                                              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | remainders | eq_ref | PRIMARY               | PRIMARY               | 4       | mytable.crawl.remainder    |      1 |                                              |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+-----------------------+-----------------------+---------+----------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
5 rows in set (2.26 sec)
```

EDIT #1:
As per the comments I've replaced the Left Joins w/ Joins and moved the date filter by the join. This did not reduce the query time, sadly.

```
SELECT crawl.pk Pk,domains.domain Domain, CONCAT(schemes.scheme, "://", domains.domain, remainders.remainder) Uri, crawl.redirect Redirect
FROM crawl
JOIN schemes ON crawl.scheme=schemes.pk
JOIN domains ON crawl.domain=domains.pk
JOIN remainders ON crawl.remainder=remainders.pk
JOIN dates ON crawl.date_crawled=dates.pk AND dates.date < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
WHERE crawl.redirect=0
GROUP BY crawl.domain
ORDER BY crawl.date_crawled ASC
LIMIT 50
```

EDIT #2:
My updated Explain:

```
+----+-------------+------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+---------+----------------------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type   | possible_keys                                           | key                   | key_len | ref                        | rows   | Extra                                                     |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+---------+----------------------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | dates      | range  | PRIMARY,date,date_pk,dateBtreeIdx,pk                     | date_pk                | 3       | NULL                       |      4 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | crawl      | ref    | domain_remainder,remainder,scheme,date_crawled_redirect | date_crawled_redirect | 8       | mytable.dates.pk,const     | 408644 |                                                           |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | schemes    | ALL    | PRIMARY                                                 | NULL                  | NULL    | NULL                       |      2 | Using where; Using join buffer                            |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | domains    | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                 | PRIMARY               | 4       | mytable.crawl.domain       |      1 |                                                           |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | remainders | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                 | PRIMARY               | 4       | mytable.crawl.remainder    |      1 |                                                           |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+---------+----------------------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

EDIT #3

```
+----+--------------------+------------+-----------------+------------------------------------------+---------+---------+----------------------------+---------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table      | type            | possible_keys                            | key     | key_len | ref                        | rows    | Extra                           |
+----+--------------------+------------+-----------------+------------------------------------------+---------+---------+----------------------------+---------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | schemes    | ALL             | PRIMARY                                  | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                       |       2 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | crawl      | ref             | domain_remainder,remainder,scheme,domain | scheme  | 4       | mytable.schemes.pk         | 1448223 | Using where                     |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | domains    | eq_ref          | PRIMARY                                  | PRIMARY | 4       | mytable.crawl.domain       |       1 |                                 |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | remainders | eq_ref          | PRIMARY                                  | PRIMARY | 4       | mytable.crawl.remainder    |       1 |                                 |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | dates      | unique_subquery | PRIMARY,date,date_pk,dateBtreeIdx,pk     | PRIMARY | 4       | func                       |       1 | Using where                     |
+----+--------------------+------------+-----------------+------------------------------------------+---------+---------+----------------------------+---------+---------------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

EDIT #4:

```
+----+-------------+------------+--------+--------------------------------------+-------------------------+---------+----------------------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type   | possible_keys                        | key                     | key_len | ref                        | rows    | Extra                                                     |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+--------------------------------------+-------------------------+---------+----------------------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | dates      | range  | PRIMARY,date,date_pk,dateBtreeIdx,pk | date_pk                 | 3       | NULL                       |       4 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | schemes    | ALL    | PRIMARY                              | NULL                    | NULL    | NULL                       |       2 | Using join buffer                                         |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | crawl      | ref    | scheme_domain_remainder              | scheme_domain_remainder | 4       | mytable.schemes.pk         | 1455517 | Using where                                               |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | domains    | eq_ref | PRIMARY                              | PRIMARY                 | 4       | mytable.crawl.domain       |       1 |                                                           |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | remainders | eq_ref | PRIMARY                              | PRIMARY                 | 4       | mytable.crawl.remainder    |       1 |                                                           |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+--------------------------------------+-------------------------+---------+----------------------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

EDIT #5

```
SELECT urls.pk PK, domains.domain Domain, CONCAT(schemes.scheme, "://", domains.domain, remainders.remainder) Uri, urls.redirect Redirect, urls.date_crawled DC FROM
(SELECT * FROM (
 SELECT * FROM crawl as urls ORDER BY date_crawled ASC
) AS tmp GROUP BY tmp.domain ) as urls
JOIN schemes ON urls.scheme=schemes.pk
JOIN domains ON urls.domain=domains.pk
JOIN remainders ON urls.remainder=remainders.pk
JOIN dates ON urls.date_crawled=dates.pk AND dates.date < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
WHERE urls.redirect=0
ORDER BY urls.date_crawled ASC
LIMIT 50
```

Comment: Just to confirm.. you want all records OLDER THAN 30 DAYS??? or did you mean >  to get all records WITHIN THE last 30 days.  Your indexes otherwise appear ok

Comment: 50 records that are older than 30 days.

Comment: do you need left joins for all of these? and try putting the conditions in the WHERE to be a part of your joins themselves.

Comment: @JohnRuddell: I suppose I don't need the left joins. I'm not sure what you mean by the second part ;)

Comment: try it without the left joins.. and the condition on a join would look like this. `LEFT JOIN dates ON crawl.date_crawled=dates.pk AND dates.date < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY`

Comment: @JohnRuddell: I've made the changes but it didn't seem to speed it up. See Edit #1. thx!

Comment: have you also tried using force index? just to ensure its using it?

Comment: @JohnRuddell I just tried to force index on "domain_remainder", then separately on "date_crawled_redirect", then separately on "domain". Again, no speedup in either case.

Comment: well... in this case I would literally need to run queries on your db to see why its messed up :( sorry i'm outta tricks lol

Comment: Break it down, run it with just the crawl table (and dates table if you have to have it), see how it performs.  If that is fine, add one table at a time until you see which is slowing it down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a nearly optimal query at hand. The only problem results from a not-optimal index in table `dates`. As you can see in your `EXPLAIN` output MySQL is not able to use any index in table `dates` so it is used as first table. This leads to a semi-optimal execution plan for your table `crawl` with a huge number of lines to be accessed.

To improve this you should add an `BTREE` index on your `dates.date` column:

```
ALTER TABLE dates ADD INDEX dateBtreeIdx USING BTREE (date)
```

BTREE-indices are used for range-conditions. In your case the "lower than", [see here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index-btree-hash.html).

Based on that you can try to add the join-field `Dates.pk` to the index as well. This might Speed up your query further, but depends on your data.

**Edit**

Now MySQL can use the Index on `date.dates` (type = RANGE and rows = 4). You don't see a speedup because now the optimizer wont use the `PRIMARY KEY` in `schemes`...

But the big Performance-issue stays with `crawl`. Try a different Approach with `IN` queries:

```
SELECT 
    crawl.pk Pk, domains.domain Domain, 
    CONCAT(schemes.scheme, "://", domains.domain, remainders.remainder) Uri, 
    crawl.redirect Redirect 
FROM 
    crawl, schemes, domains, remainders
WHERE 
    crawl.scheme=schemes.pk
    AND crawl.domain=domains.pk
    AND crawl.remainder=remainders.pk

    AND crawl.date_crawled IN (SELECT pk FROM dates WHERE (dates.date < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY))
    AND crawl.redirect=0 

GROUP BY 
    crawl.domain 
ORDER BY 
    crawl.date_crawled ASC 
LIMIT 50
```

**Edit #2**

```
SELECT 
    urls.pk PK, domains.domain Domain, 
    CONCAT(schemes.scheme, "://", domains.domain, remainders.remainder) Uri, 
    urls.redirect Redirect, 
    urls.date_crawled DC 
FROM 
    (SELECT pk, redirect, date_crawled FROM crawl GROUP BY `domain` ) as urls
JOIN schemes ON urls.scheme=schemes.pk
JOIN domains ON urls.`domain`=domains.pk
JOIN remainders ON urls.remainder=remainders.pk
JOIN dates ON urls.date_crawled=dates.pk AND dates.date < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
WHERE 
    urls.redirect=0
ORDER BY urls.date_crawled ASC
LIMIT 50
```

Comment: Thx for the suggestion but unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: What does your `EXPLAIN` says now?

Comment: See my Edit #2. The date_pk is the new index as suggested. I also tried pk_date as well as dateBtreeIdx alone. Neither of them sped it up.

Comment: Try the `IN` queries in my updated answer - will it Change the execution plan given by `EXPLAIN`? Can you move to MariaDB and use its matrialization-Features?

Comment: See Edit #3. This does make sense but it seemed to slow down the query.

Comment: Add a combined index on crawls `scheme`,`domain` and `remainder`.

Comment: EDIT #4 has my Explain statement for that. I had to force the index in order to make it use "scheme_domain_remainder". Without the force it uses "date_crawled_redirect". No speedup in the query with or without force.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64589/discussion-between-benni-and-llamawithabowlcut).

Comment: Did this Speed up your query further?

Comment: Not really...thanks for your help. I opened a bounty and will award it to you in 23 hours when S.O. lets me.